# Is there a way to handle locked file from command line and release it?

Tags: windows, command-line, locked-files

Is there a way to detect locked files in specify folder and release them by command line?

Something like this in pseudo-code:

```
for file in folder do
unlock file
```

Comment: What's the real problem?

Comment: -1! Bad question for http://stackoverflow.com .. must be asked on http://superuser.com

Comment: @Asif Did you know that you can use the "flag" link underneath the question's tags to suggest that it be migrated to another, more appropriate site?

Comment: A guy asks if a specific feature in the Windows API exists so he can write a utility program, and that's not a programming question and belongs on superuser?  I don't get it.

Comment: The question doesn't ask if the feature exists in the Windows API, he asks for a way to do it by the command line. The command line is not a programming language, or a programmatic interface. It's a user interface, just like Windows Explorer.

Comment: This is a task that a programmer is likely to have to do. If you must move the question, go ahead and move it. But for a programmer who just wants to get something done, closing a question like this just gets in the way. It is frankly by far the most annoying thing that regularly happens on SO.

Comment: @CodyGray - There are probably several people who hang in the [cmd] tag that might disagree with you.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, this is possible using a free utility called **Handle**, by Mark Russinovich.

It can be download [here from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655).

This runs from the command line, and will tell you which program has a particular file or directory open, based on whether it has an open *handle* to that resource.

By running `handle.exe` with the `-c` flag, you can also force the specified handle closed, which will unlock the resource. But fair warning: this will likely cause the application using the resource to crash, perhaps even the entire system to become unstable. So I wouldn't make a habit of doing this; only use it for special cases like debugging where you expect some instability.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it harder to work with handle.exe, because it should to get the pid, i want to create a batch file that know to search foreach a file is in the specific folder and unlock it..

Comment: @David Harder than what? That seems like a really strange plan. If applications are *using* those files and you close all the handles, you've got a serious problem on your hands.

Answer (score -4):

No, you can't you have to close the application holding the lock first. [Unlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker) may help you locate the source of the lock - if it's a crashed application then you'll be able to terminate it's process.

Comment: If Unlocker can do it, then there is a programmatic way to do it. Otherwise, Unlocker wouldn't work.

Comment: Unlocker is terrible. Lock Hunter is at least usable.