# How to kill a hung windows ftp service in Windows 7

Tags: service, ftp, iis-7.5, kill-process, hung

When I try to stop the Microsoft FTP Service using the net stop ftpsvc command in a Windows 7 32bit (IIS 7.5) machine it just says stopping and ....... and hangs. It remains there indefinitely, I can't stop or start it.

When I look at the processes through task manager I can see svchost ftpsvc running, I try to kill it using teh task manager (from the Process Details page) nothing happens. I try to kill it using taskkill and the PID through an administrative command prompt and it says process terminated but i can see if running in task manager process details. I try to kill it using process explorer and nothing happens.

This happens is a user is downloading a file and then I try to do a net stop ftpsvc in between.

There are no child processes. Any idea what's going on and if there's some way to kill this process without rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try force-kill?
Run this from command line:

```
sc queryex ftpsvc
```

Then you will get Process Id which can be used to taskkill with f switch:

```
taskkill /f /pid [PID]
```

Comment: Yes and looks like you didn't read the question completely or the comments. I've tried taskkill and the task manager. All the basic things. It didn't work.

Comment: Yes I did try it. I also used process explorer

Comment: @rboy, I see. In this case, my answer isn't helpful at all. But let me leave it there for others' reference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the process details section of task manager and kill the process. We have a message query service that often refuses to stop. Then refresh the services page and start it again.

Second part:  The file will be partially uploaded or downloaded. It is the client applications responsibility to do those checks. There will be no locks on ftp.

Comment: I mentioned above that I tried killing it through Task Manager, Process explorer and taskkill - it didn't work.

Comment: btw the ftpsvc locks the file, I verified the same using some tools. If I unlock the file handle by force the systems becomes unstable. so I was trying to stop the service so that it can release the file locks so I can update the file

Comment: @rboy I would have not thought that the standard process of FTP Up/Down would normally lock the file - I didn't think it could.  This is why it is possible to partially upload or download a file and then having to confirm its size once you are done.  (Hence my comment on client responsibility).

Comment: I don't think its the up down creating the lock, the lock is taken when someone tries to download a file, it just doesn't release the lock which is why bring it down hangs.

Comment: so again it come back to the question - is there any way to kill a process that doesn't seem to get killed by any of the methods mentioned above

Comment: Nope - I did not.  I generally need a good reason to down-vote.

Comment: You can also look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10672497/1662973.  There is a discussion around killing file handles - which may be the root cause here.

Comment: I use another GUI based app called Unlocker which tells me which prcoess is locking teh file and then gives me an option to kill the  process or unlock the handle. if I unlock the handle it makes the system unstable, if I select kills the process, it isn't able to (same reason above)

Comment: Are you able to kill the process via the details section off task manager? Nothing should survive a kill there.

Comment: No, nothing happens when I end process or end process tree